# python: typecast object in dict()

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following code

```
histos = dict()
for key in list:
  obj = file.Get(key)
  if not key in histos:
    histos[key] = obj.Clone()
  else
    histos[key].Add(obj)
```

`Add()` is a function of `obj`, however I get the following error if the object is retrieved from a python `dict()`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./script.py", line 35, in <module>
    histos[key].Add(obj)
AttributeError: 'PyROOT_NoneType' object has no attribute 'Add'
```

How can I typecast objects retrieved from `dict()`

Comment: I can't see what you'd want to "typecast" here, or what you'd typecast it to.

Comment: They would be objects of type Histo

Comment: `my_dict.update({'New key 2': 'New value 2', 'New key 3': 'New value 3'})` is that what you wherre looking for ?

Comment: no, I want to modify an object already inside a dict

Comment: But the item is not a Histo object. Even if "typecasting" was a thing in Python, which it isn't, you can't make an object into something completely different.

Comment: Obviously you have at least one key whose values is a `PyROOT_None` instance (whatever this might be - it's not part of the language nor stdlib) and obviously this object doesn't have a `Add` method. You'd better fix this instead of looking for "solutions" that won't fix anything (and actually there's NO "typecasting" in Python).